# How to make a folder UAC protected

Tags: windows, security, permissions, uac, restriction

Can someone tell me how (in Windows 7 PRO) I can create a folder, so when I try to open it, User Account Control will ask for a Administrator's password. I need to restrict a folder on the C: drive, only be opened by administrators, and if a normal user tries to open it, he will need the Administrator's password.

Comment: what type of computer??

Comment: I voted to close since this question as off topic, but here's something for you to try. At the command line you can disable inheritance and copy the existing ACLs: `icacls TargetFolder /inheritance:d`; remove the entries for regular users: `icacls TargetFolder /remove Users /remove "Authenticated Users"`; and set the integrity label to high with inheritance for folders (containers) and files (objects): `icacls TargetFolder /setintegritylevel (CI)(OI)High`. It should retain the rights granted to Administrators and SYSTEM.

Answer (score 2):

You could go to Control Panel, then you go to User Account and Family Safety. Then go to Parental Control and unable it, or get your user off the list. After that, you should be able to do it.

(AT LEAST IT WORKS FOR ME!)

Comment: For other users, add them to the Parental Control